# Magento Search Not Working

Tags: magento-1.7, catalogsearch, ce-1.9.0.1

I have a new website that is running Magento 1.7.0.2.

When you search in the search bar for say "totem" nothing pulls up, instead it says no results can be found. I know there are results, but if you search specifically by the SKU  like "tn truth-1" than a product will show up.

This was happening before I installed the search with the drop down.

Debugging Steps I have taken:

- Clear Cache
- Re-Index Site
- Went to System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search and set Search Type to Combine (Like and Fulltext)
- Re-indexed Site
- Cleared Cache
- Installed Searchanise http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/searchanise-connector-add-on-2652.html
- Check var/report - Nothing
- Checked the logs and there is nothing
- Went to stock theme and all plugins disabled

At this point I am not sure what else to do, I would love to give you code example, but I am afraid those won't help because there is no custom coding with the search, especially seeing that it didn't work when I put everything to stock Magento and no plugins.

If you need code or a stack trace, just let me know and I would be happy to get those to you if you tell me what files and how to make the stack trace since nothing is logging right now.

Comment: What are you searching for (keyword wise), and what attributes do you have setup to be included in the search index?

Comment: I am searching by like the product name.

Comment: Look under `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes`.  Look for `Name` and post back what is says in the `Searchable` column.

Comment: Says Yes and it is set to Global

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the help of @Axel I was able to fix the issue.

After digging into the Attributes and comparing the settings of the SKU since I could search by that and the settings of Name and Desc. I noticed a few differences.

here is what the SKU was set to

[image]

Here is what name was set to before I changed it

[image]

This is what I changed Name to

[image]

After that I re-indexed the site and then cleared the cache manually via ftp var/cache and deleted all folders in the cache then refreshed the site and tried to search and sure enough it works now.

Thank you Axel for pointing me in the right direction.

I also hope this helps anyone else having an issue with the search.

Comment: Glad you figured it out ;)