# Search not working Magento 1.9.0 rwd

Tags: catalogsearch, search

I am using magento RWD theme for my project and have made some customization in the theme.

But my search is not working in it.

Few things I have tried are:-

1. Reindexing data.
2. Flush magento cache.
3. Went to System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search and set Search Type to Combine (Like and Fulltext)
4. `http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7335/magento-search-not-working`

All are of no avail.
I have created a gist of required files.
https://gist.github.com/bhargavmehta/4aee123a93e07b4db60c

Can Anyone point out the error?

Demo url :- http://infigic.com/ds4u/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out many solutions to it and created a blog to how I solved this issue.

You can find solutions here at [Magento Search solution](http://www.infigic.com/magento-search-not-working/)